# Summary formatting

Tags: r, dataframe, formatting

The normal output of a `summary()` function is this:

```
> summary(iris[, -5])
  Sepal.Length    Sepal.Width     Petal.Length    Petal.Width   
 Min.   :4.300   Min.   :2.000   Min.   :1.000   Min.   :0.100  
 1st Qu.:5.100   1st Qu.:2.800   1st Qu.:1.600   1st Qu.:0.300  
 Median :5.800   Median :3.000   Median :4.350   Median :1.300  
 Mean   :5.843   Mean   :3.057   Mean   :3.758   Mean   :1.199  
 3rd Qu.:6.400   3rd Qu.:3.300   3rd Qu.:5.100   3rd Qu.:1.800  
 Max.   :7.900   Max.   :4.400   Max.   :6.900   Max.   :2.500
```

I wanted to transpose it and than get it into a data frame, so I did this:

```
> trans <- as.data.frame(t(as.matrix(unclass(summary(iris[, -5])))))
> trans
                           V1              V2              V3              V4              V5
 Sepal.Length Min.   :4.300   1st Qu.:5.100   Median :5.800   Mean   :5.843   3rd Qu.:6.400  
 Sepal.Width  Min.   :2.000   1st Qu.:2.800   Median :3.000   Mean   :3.057   3rd Qu.:3.300  
 Petal.Length Min.   :1.000   1st Qu.:1.600   Median :4.350   Mean   :3.758   3rd Qu.:5.100  
 Petal.Width  Min.   :0.100   1st Qu.:0.300   Median :1.300   Mean   :1.199   3rd Qu.:1.800  
                           V6
 Sepal.Length Max.   :7.900  
 Sepal.Width  Max.   :4.400  
 Petal.Length Max.   :6.900  
 Petal.Width  Max.   :2.500
```

The problem comes now. A more logical format, I believe, would be this:

```
> trans <- cbind(rownames(trans), trans)
> rownames(trans) <- NULL
> colnames(trans) <- c("Treatment", "Minimum", "1st Quartile", "Median", "Mean", "3rd Quartile", "Maximum")
> trans
      Treatment         Minimum    1st Quartile          Median            Mean    3rd Quartile
1  Sepal.Length Min.   :4.300   1st Qu.:5.100   Median :5.800   Mean   :5.843   3rd Qu.:6.400  
2   Sepal.Width Min.   :2.000   1st Qu.:2.800   Median :3.000   Mean   :3.057   3rd Qu.:3.300  
3  Petal.Length Min.   :1.000   1st Qu.:1.600   Median :4.350   Mean   :3.758   3rd Qu.:5.100  
4   Petal.Width Min.   :0.100   1st Qu.:0.300   Median :1.300   Mean   :1.199   3rd Qu.:1.800  
          Maximum
1 Max.   :7.900  
2 Max.   :4.400  
3 Max.   :6.900  
4 Max.   :2.500
```

But then, as you can see, the column names are repeated in each cell. This is something very unappealing. Therefore, my question is whether it's possible to remove this part from the data.frame, leaving me with this:

```
      Treatment         Minimum    1st Quartile          Median            Mean    3rd Quartile
1  Sepal.Length         4.300      5.100                 5.800            5.843      6.400  
2  Sepal.Width          2.000      2.800                 3.000            3.057      3.300  
3  Petal.Length         1.000      1.600                 4.350            3.758      5.100  
4  Petal.Width          0.100      0.300                 1.300            1.199      1.800  
          Maximum
1          7.900  
2          4.400  
3          6.900  
4          2.500
```

One advantage of doing this will also be that my data.frame will then be numeric (possibly), as well as just overall neater. How can I do this?

Comment: You could also look into the ‘summarize()’ function from the dplyr package, it might have better output and control that the summary function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several packages allow you to summarize data in this way. For instance, my [modelsummary package](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/datasummary.html) (self-promotion alert!) allows you to do this:

```r
library(modelsummary)

datasummary(All(iris) ~ Min + P25 + P50 + Mean + P75 + Max, 
            data = iris,
            output = "data.frame")
#>                 Min  P25  P50 Mean  P75  Max
#> 1 Sepal.Length 4.30 5.10 5.80 5.84 6.40 7.90
#> 2  Sepal.Width 2.00 2.80 3.00 3.06 3.30 4.40
#> 3 Petal.Length 1.00 1.60 4.35 3.76 5.10 6.90
#> 4  Petal.Width 0.10 0.30 1.30 1.20 1.80 2.50
```

Dropping the `output` argument produces an HTML table that looks like this:

[image]

And calling this:

```r
datasummary_skim(iris)
```

Produces this:

[image]